# what if call to async is not awaited

Tags: .net, async-await

Do I need to await the async calls I am using from Azure client library

```
MyFunction()
{
  //break data load into blocks and upload individual block
  {
    BlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockIdBase64, 
      new MemoryStream(dataBytes, bytesRead, bytesPerChunk), 
      null);
  }

  // commit all the blocks to the blob
  BlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blocklist);
}
```

Comment: Yes. You do need to await async calls.

Comment: @I3arnon: No you don't.  The compiler will warn you if you don't, but it won't stop you.

Comment: @David the compiler will also compile a deadlock. It doesn't mean you need to write it. There are cases where you don't need (or even shouldn't) await an async call. But considering this question has zero information then the guideline should be that "You do need to await async calls"

Comment: The correct answer also depends heavily on the context. Is this an ASP.NET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to await them, no.  That's essentially what makes them asynchronous.  At some point in the stack something needs to invoke the asynchronous operation and *not* wait for it in order for any of it to be asynchronous.

The code will execute synchronously until it reaches an asynchronous operation *within the method itself*.  At that point the system will put the rest of the `async` method in a `ContinueWith()` and return control to your calling code.

You *should*, however, do *something* with the resulting task.  Otherwise you're looking at a "fire and forget" situation where you would never know if anything went wrong.  This could be as simple as:

```
BlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blocklist).ContinueWith(t => {
    // t is the returned Task.  Check it for errors, respond to its state, etc.
});
```

Side Note: This is precisely why `async void` should be avoided.  It doesn't return a `Task` and therefore can't be handled like this.

Comment: That is **not** what makes async calls asynchronous. They are still asynchronous when you await them.

Comment: @I3arnon: Perhaps my terminology could use some clarity.  But awaiting an asynchronous operation halts execution of the consuming code until that operation is complete.  Somewhere in the stack something has to *not* await the operation.